# LocalStorage not working with slideToggle (working with toggle)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using slidetoggle(); to toggle a banner and localStorage to remember the last state of the banner that has been toggled.

localStorage works fine with toggle(); , although with slideToggle(); it does not anymore. Also when I add animation to toggle (i.e toggle(500);) localStorage also does not work anymore.

```
   $('#button').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings().slideToggle();
        localStorage.setItem('display', $(this).siblings().is(':hidden'));
    });
    var block = localStorage.getItem('display');
    if (block == 'true') {
        $('#banner').hide()
    }
```

What could be the issue?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9pj9ws5u/12/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it should be done:

```
$(this).siblings().slideToggle(function() {
    // Code is triggered once the animations finished and the element is hidden
    // $(this) - reference to the SIBLING element
    localStorage.setItem('display', $(this).is(':hidden'));
});
```

Your code didn't worked because you checked if it was hidden before the animation completed. Putting the logic inside the animation callback function ensure it's called once the animation is finished.

Comment: Might be good to add an explanation of why it didn't work previously.